# Python 3 codification problem: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xed'

Tags: python-3.x, apache, unicode, ascii, cgi

I am developing a Python app which iterates through an Elasticsearch instance and stores all the documents into an HTML file. I am using Apache 2 as the server and I get always the same unicode error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xed'.

I've tried encoding the string with encode('utf-8') and it seems to avoid the error, but I get the output in the wrong format: 
'b'Assidue  As\xc3\xadduamente.

This is the Python code:

```
for row in resp["hits"]["hits"]:
    post = row['_source']['text']
    fichero_html.write(post)
```

The elasticsearch documents store words in spanish, so the graphic accents need to be correctly displayed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:

This code works fine on the Python3 console, but it does not work on the server side.

```
for row in resp["hits"]["hits"]:
    post = (row['_source']['text'])+"</br></br>"
    post = post.encode('utf8')
    post = post.decode('utf8')
    fichero_html.write(post)
```

May it be something related to the apache server configuration?

Comment: Thank you, I've tried changing the ES instance as it is shown on that post, but I have the same problem. I get b'D\xc3\xbcsseldorf' instead of Düsseldorf on the HTML. And if I do not use the encoding I still get the UnicodeEncodedError. There's something I am missing, maybe because I am very new with Python encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting codec/searching Elasticsearch for unicode values from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437913/setting-codec-searching-elasticsearch-for-unicode-values-from-python)